# SAP UI5 Component development metadata datatypes

Tags: sapui5

I'm developing a component for UI5. In the metadata->properties part I want to define a property of the type Integer. If I set the data type by `"markerSize" : {type:"integer",defaultValue:"25"}` (or any other variation like Integer, Number, number) I get the errormessage that 50 (the current value) can't be accessed by "in". Changing the data type to string is working. In the examples from SAP I can only find "`string`" and "`sap.ui.core.CSSSize`" as datatype. How can I define numeric values? Is there a list of supported datatypes an their correct definition?

KR,
Nico

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use int as data type, then your defaultValue should not be a string (although it causes no error...). Your problem is that instead of "integer" you have to use "int". so please try this here:

```
{ type:"int",defaultValue: 25 }
```

That should work. This code worked for me:

```
<script>

    sap.ui.core.Control.extend("my.Control", {
        metadata : {
            properties : {
                "text" : "string",
                "size" : {type: "int", defaultValue: 500 }
            },
        },

        renderer : function(oRm, oControl) {  
            oRm.write("<div>size = "+oControl.getSize()+"</div>") 
        }

    });

    var myControl = new my.Control({text:"Hello"});
    myControl.placeAt("content");        
</script>    

<body class='sapUiBody'>
    <div id='content'></div>
</body>
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! Solved the problem.

Comment: I have one additional question:
What about other datatypes? Arrays or Floats?

Comment: You can read this in the UI5 documentation: A property is defined by at least its name and its type. Additionally, the default value of the property can be defined. So the available settings are:

type: The data type of the Control property. Automatic type validation is done in the UI5 core. Examples for valid types are:
string for a string property (default),
int or float for number properties,
int[] etc. for arrays,
sap.ui.core.CSSSize for a custom-defined type

Comment: @user3042011 make sure to highlight the correct answer to make it visible for other users. thanks.

Comment: Sorry for being late... For other datatypes you could simply look at my SAPUI5 tutorials, especially [this one](https://www.nabisoft.com/tutorials/sapui5/creating-custom-controls-in-sapui5).